# How to get a random card from a deck of cards?

Tags: python

I have code of a generator that generates a deck of cards.
Now I want to get 1 random card from the deck and print it,
but it seems I can't do it.
Random.choice doesn't work for it.
i´ve tried to manually add the value + suit + color, but that doesnt work either.
Im new to coding and please forgive me for not understanding coding.

edit: translated to english.

```
from random import random


values = list(range(2,15))
suits = ["♣","♦","♥","♠"]
colors = ["black","red"]


#making the high value cards to the face of king, qeen, etc
face_cards = {
    "J": 11,
    "Q": 12,
    "K": 13,
    "A": 14,
    11: "J",
    12: "Q",
    13: "K",
    14: "A"
}

class card:
    def __init__(self,value,suit,color):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        self.color = color
    
#Makes the deck of cards in a cards []
def deck_of_cards(values, suits,colors):
    cards = []
    for value in values:
        for suit in suits:
            for color in colors:
                if value in face_cards:
                    card_value = face_cards[value]
                    cards.append(card(card_value,suit,color))
                   
                    
                else:
                    cards.append(card(value, suit,color))
                    
                    
    return cards

ask = input("do you want a random card from the deck ?(yes or no): ")
cards = deck_of_cards(values,suits,colors)

if ask == "yes":
    print("The random card is: ",random.choice(cards)) # This line is suposed to print 1 random card from the list cards,
                                                        # but the list doesnt seem to work the way i wanted it to work
else:
    cards = deck_of_cards(values,suits,colors)
    for card in cards:    #This function is required to print the deck
        print(card.value, card.suit,card.color)
```

Comment: What is `Random`?  The built-in module that contains the `.choice()` function you're looking for is named `random`, instead - but I see no `import` statements at all here.

Comment: I recommend that you look at [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) and especially at https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles. These conventions are very well respected, and not following them makes your code harder to read for those used to them. Also, note that using non English variable names doesn't help to understand what your code does...

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `from random import random` to `import random`, since the choice() function is located directly in the "random" module.

Also, for a good display of the selected map, you can override the `__str__()` method in the `class card`:

```
class card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit, color):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.color} {self.value} {self.suit}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code, and then made a few tweaks to provide a random selection of cards in the spirit of your project.  Following is the code with the tweaks.

```
import random           # Changed the import declaration

values = list(range(2,15))
suits = ["♣","♦","♥","♠"]
colors = ["black","red"]

#making the high value cards to the face of king, qeen, etc
face_cards = {
    "J": 11,
    "Q": 12,
    "K": 13,
    "A": 14,
    11: "J",
    12: "Q",
    13: "K",
    14: "A"
}

class card:
    def __init__(self,value,suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        if self.suit == "♣" or self.suit == "♠":    # Stick to standard colors for suits
            self.color = colors[0]
        else:
            self.color = colors[1]
    
#Makes the deck of cards in a cards []
def deck_of_cards(values, suits):
    cards = []
    for value in values:
        for suit in suits:
            if value in face_cards:
                card_value = face_cards[value]
                cards.append(card(card_value,suit))
            else:
                cards.append(card(value, suit))
                    
    return cards

cards = deck_of_cards(values,suits)

while True:                                 # Allow for multiple selections

    ask = input("do you want a random card from the deck ?(yes/no/quit): ") # Added a quit option
    
    if ask == "quit":
        break

    if ask == "yes":
        chosen = random.randint(0, 51)      # Generate a random number
        print("The random card is: ", cards[chosen].value, "of", cards[chosen].suit) # Then, get the card associated with that index
                                                        
    else:
        cards = deck_of_cards(values,suits)
        for card in cards:    #This function is required to print the deck
            print(card.value, card.suit,card.color)
```

First off, to make a random selection, a variable was added that would contain a random value between "0" and "51".  This value would then be used as an index to your card deck to display the card.  Also, in keeping with standard card deck colors, I removed the need to pass a color onto the card deck creation and just based the color on the usual and customary color of suits (e.g. "hearts" are red, "spades" are black).  And I added a "while" loop so that a user can make multiple selections.

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.